# Record select option values HTML in Chrome application.

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a form within a chrome application that has the below options.

```
<select name="option" id="option_id">
<option value="1">[No number listed]</option>
<option value="2">[Not answered]</option>
<option value="3">[Answered – not oncall – assisted with issue]</option>
<option value="4">[Answered – not oncall – unavailable]</option>
<option value="5">[Answered – oncall - unavailable]</option>
<option value="6">[Answered – oncall - available]</option>
</select>
```

What I want to be able to do is after the user selects a value and clicks the submit button

```
<button name="Log" type="submit" id="Log-submit" data submit="...Sending">Log</button>
```

I want each value to be recorded somewhere centrally.
What tools would be best suited? and what would be the simplest methodology?

I only want to record them simply row by row

Example

```
[Answered – oncall - available]
[Answered – oncall - available]
[Answered – oncall - available]
[Answered – oncall - available]
[Answered – oncall - available]
[Answered – oncall - available]
[Answered – oncall - available]
```

This is a chrome application only I will use, so I want to record either to my local disk (probably not possible) or can anyone recommend a something lightweight an easy to use?

I really just want to record the outcomes of me selecting these values everytime I use it. I'M stumped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). This way you can save the log when user clicks the button and restore it when window loads. It will be saved in your browser's data, so it will be available even after the page is closed and opened again.

```js
var choices = localStorage.getItem('savedOptions'); // try loading saved choices
if (!choices) {
  // if nothing is saved, initialize with empty array
  choices = [];
} else {
  // you can only store strings in localStorage, so we should parse saved JSON
  choices = JSON.parse(choices);
}

// ... Do anything with loaded choices ...

// Here's how to save new choices to the array

var select = document.querySelector('#option_id');
var logButton = document.querySelector('#log');
var savedDisplay = document.querySelector('#saved');

logButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // add choice to saved list
  choices.push(select.options[select.selectedIndex].text);
  // save the list in localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('savedOptions', JSON.stringify(choices));
});
```

```html
<select name="option" id="option_id">
  <option value="1">[No number listed]</option>
  <option value="2">[Not answered]</option>
  <option value="3">[Answered – not oncall – assisted with issue]</option>
  <option value="4">[Answered – not oncall – unavailable]</option>
  <option value="5">[Answered – oncall - unavailable]</option>
  <option value="6">[Answered – oncall - available]</option>
</select>
<button id="log">Log</button>
```